# will come vs are coming

Tags: future-time

Tonight is the night when my brother come with his wife at my house. Could you say how is better to say this information and what is the difference?

> Don’t forget that my brother and his wife will come to us tonight.

vs

> Don’t forget that my brother and his wife are coming to us tonight.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same, but don't include "to us" in either.  It sounds wrong.  You can remove "his", and it is probably better if you do remove it.  My preference is the second:

> Don't forget that my brother and wife are coming tonight.